# Specify browser to use for ioslides presentation

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, rstudio, ioslides

I created an ioslides project with shiny runtime in RStudio.

For practical reasons, i want to use the browser for presentation instead of RStudio's viewer. Is there a way to specify (e.g. in the markdown document header) which browser to use for displaying of the HTML file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening Shiny App directly in the default browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311318/opening-shiny-app-directly-in-the-default-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to use firefox, then locate it and put it the options:

```
options(browser = "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe")
```

like this:

```
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server),host="192.168.xx.xx",port=5013, launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is suitable when running a shiny application, i am looking for a similiar solution for an ioslides presentation containing shiny applications