# Shiny downloadButton and downloadLink default directory or filename

Tags: r, download, shiny

The download handler is a remarkably popular shiny tool - even for local work. However it is quite annoying when it opens up all the time in the R-Studio directory. Here is the current example program from the Shiny documantion.

```
library(shiny)

## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    downloadLink("downloadData", "Download")
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
    # Our dataset
    data <- mtcars

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(data, file)
      }
    )
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

It opens like this:
[image]

A few related questions:

- Is there anyway to override that directory to something more reasonable?
- Can I specify the default name anywhere (the default is a bit bizarrely take from the name of the output list name).
- Any insights as to why this is so would be welcome. There seems to be nothing in the docs around this.

Comment: Since this is browser dependent, would it work to tell the app to open in a different browser? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311318/opening-shiny-app-directly-in-the-default-browser

Comment: You mean the default directory is browser dependent? Or the code? I also don't see how that would help.

Comment: The default directory is browser dependent.  When I open your app in Chrome or IE, it automatically saves to 'C:/Users/myuser/Downloads', which is the default directory listed to those browsers.  I'm not sure how the RStudio browser works, but it's default directory is clearly something different.

Comment: Ah - that is a good insight.

Comment: R-Studio is an Electron app, thus browser based. Might be documented in the Electron docs.

Comment: and now that I think about it, you could also use `choose.dir` and give the directory you want to start in. How you decide the appropriate starting place is a more complicated question, but for local use you could probably come up with something reasonable. (`getwd`, or some such)

Comment: Not really clear where I would put `choose.dir` in a Shiny program using `downloadHandler` though. Nor would I want to browse twice.