# How do I get the R Shiny downloadHandler filename to work?

Tags: r, linux, user-interface, download, shiny

I am setting up a Shiny app that allows the user to download a custom dataset. Following the [tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/download.html), I set up the [downloadHandler](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/downloadHandler.html) following the example given in the [docs](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/downloadHandler.html) (reproduced here, since the same thing happens if I copy and paste this).

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadLink("downloadData", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Our dataset
  data <- mtcars

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Problem:**

This issue only comes up on my Linux* system and seems to work just fine on a Mac. The download and everything works just fine, but the "Save" GUI does not offer me the right file name. There is no error message or warning. Based on my input,

- I'd expect it to give me *data-TIME.csv*, i.e. the input to `filename`. (It does not work either if I give it simple string in that slot).
- but it offers me *DownloadData* or whatever name I give to the `output` variable (cf. screenshot).

[image]

**Question:**

- Is this a OS issue as I suspect, or am I doing something wrong?
- How do i fix this? Can I get this to work on any system?

Thanks!

I'm running elementary OS 0.4 Loki, Built on "Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS", GTK version: 3.18.9. & RStudio 1.0.143

Answer (score 12):

If you are using the Rstudio Browser to test you App this could be the problem. I have the same issue on Windows.

When I use the Rstudio Browser the filename is not properly hand over, but **if I use Firefox everything works fine**. Your code works also fine in my Firefox.

Comment: Any idea if this can be fixed for use with RStudio browser?

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess the chance to fix it is not very high. Instead you could force to open Shiny in your default browser and not use the Rstudio browser per default: [See example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311318/opening-shiny-app-directly-in-the-default-browser)