# How to pass a filename to downloadHandler in Shiny on a Mac

Tags: r, macos, shiny

In the following minimal example I **am** able to download a PDF of a basic plot but I am having issues setting the filename of the plot that is downloaded. The argument `filename` is not passed to `downloadHander`.

After testing this on different OS's it seems to be a Mac issue. The filename is passed with no problem whilst on Windows or Linux. Does anyone know if there some Mac settings that I need to change or how I can overcome this please?

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Our dataset
  data <- mtcars
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      paste0("plot", Sys.Date(), ".pdf")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      a <- 2   # perform some operations relating to image
      f <- 4
      pdf(file = file)
      plot(data)
      dev.off()
    },
    contentType = "application/pdf"
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

When I click download, the plot is downloaded but the filename is a random name, not the output of what is passed to the argument `filename` e.g. `paste0("plot",Sys.Date(),".pdf")`

e.g.
It is see image below where it is named `RStudio-OwldbV.pdf`

[image]

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] shinydashboardPlus_0.7.5 shinydashboard_0.7.1     shinyWidgets_0.5.3       dendextend_1.14.0        tidyr_1.1.2             
 [6] patchwork_1.0.1          ggplot2_3.3.2            shinyhelper_0.3.2        colorspace_1.4-1         colourpicker_1.1.0      
[11] shinythemes_1.1.2        DT_0.15                  dplyr_1.0.2              shiny_1.5.0              MSnbase_2.14.2          
[16] ProtGenerics_1.20.0      S4Vectors_0.26.1         mzR_2.22.0               Rcpp_1.0.5               Biobase_2.48.0          
[21] BiocGenerics_0.34.0
```

Comment: @YBS I really don't care what the filename is at all, this is just an example. The issue is that whatever is placed in the argument `filename` is not getting passed to `downloadHandler`. I can edit the post as per your suggestion but this doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: Testing reveals that this is OS dependent and a Mac issue. The above code works fine and as anticipated with Windows and Linux.

Comment: This may be related to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/45568105/4651968 I have had the same problem (on Ubuntu) but when running the app from a browser rather than the RStudio viewer the filename is properly handled.