# Open shiny app in browser

Tags: r, shiny

I know that there are answers for this question but none of them helped me.

I'm using RStudio and calling a shiny app either by

1) clicking on the `Run App` button on the top right side of RStudio, or by
  2) calling `runApp("shinyApp")`

Before I got Windows 10 installed on my computer, erasing all my configurations, in both ways the app started in the browser. Now it's starting in a window of RStudio.

I already set `options(device = "windows")` in `Options.R` but of course this does not affect shiny apps.

I also tried the solution pointed out by @Pork Chop 
 in [Opening Shiny App directly in the default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311318/opening-shiny-app-directly-in-the-default-browser) but it didn't do the trick.

Of course I could go by calling `runApp("shinyApp", launch.browser=TRUE)' but I want it to do it automatically.

Comment: Did you [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35311882/680068)?

Comment: Shame on me. I didn't try it. Works perfect. Thanks

Comment: No worries we all have been there :D