# Shiny Application: ggplot() shows up in RStudio Viewer and not my mainpanel

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I've written a shiny application that functions properly with no errors, but every time I run the program, the ggplot() gets plotted in RStudio's Viewer Panel, but I want it to show up in the mainpanel. How do I get it to switch and plot in my mainPanel of my shiny application?

In my code, my mainPanel isn't inside my sidebarPanel, and my plotOutput gets called correctly.

```
mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
```

Here's the server call to plot1. All my dataframe manipulation and my `ggplot()` code is within `data1()`

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({data1()})
```

Comment: RStudio may be defaulting to showing your shiny app (which only contains a `ggplot`) in the Viewer. You can change the default settings to open your shiny app in your browser. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311318/opening-shiny-app-directly-in-the-default-browser

Comment: could you try to turn off all Panels and leave dashboardBody and see what happens
   dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
    dashboardBody(plotOutput("plot1") )

Comment: The sidebar panel pops up in the window/browser correctly, but the plot still shows up in the RStudio Viewer, even when I change the default viewer to browser.

Comment: you need to show more in the code what you are doing. if you are using `data1()` a reactive object that has the ggplot output need to look at the complete code. I am sure it is a simple fix, you need to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @user5249203 the post has been edited to show all the code

Comment: @NotAMathMan, what is the data format? Can you paste the `head(df) ` of the dataframe you are plotting? or upload your excel sheet somewhere

Comment: from what I see in your code. You need to output the ggplot on `output$plot1 <- ggplot( ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
plotOutput() and renderPlot()
```

use:

`ggiraphOutput() and renderggiraph()`