# R package googlesheets default browser change

Tags: r, google-sheets

When I run

```
#get the library
library(googlesheets)
#initialize token
gs_auth(new_user = TRUE)
```

it always opens my firebox browser, however, I want it to open my chrome browser, is there a way to change the default open browser?

By the way, my os is windows 7
R version 3.3.3
googlesheets version 0.3.0

Comment: What os are you using?

Comment: @sindri_baldur it is windows 7

Comment: Maybe Firefox is your default browser for the system? Can you check/change the default browser? https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95417?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: @Ronak Shah I did set it, unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem at present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set which browser to launch from your R session with `options(browser = "/path/to/executable")`. To launch a Chrome browser on windows this may look like:

```
options(browser = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe")
```

NB: the same command can be used to specify the browser in which to launch a shiny application, see e.g. [Opening Shiny App directly in the default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311318/opening-shiny-app-directly-in-the-default-browser/35311882)

Comment: Thanks! it works for me~ by the way, can you explain why it is always firefox initially even I change my system default browser to chrome? I checked the initial browser option in R and it is not firefox, but without your new setting it always turned to firefox, thanks!

Comment: The Details section of `?utils::browseURL` might be useful in explaining default browser behavior. Another link to temporarily change the default browser for `gs_auth`:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets/vignettes/alternative-browser.html